# How to add ID attribute with indexed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list with a class and I need add id attribute incremented, by example:

```
$('li.myClass').attr('id', 'sliderWeb-'+ Number++);
```

Some have any idea?

Comment: what you've got looks fine (assuming you replace `Number` with a variable like `i`, but it's impossible to say with only what you've provided

Comment: @BenKolyaMansley unless there is only one li being returned, that does not look fine. Each li would have the same id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('li.myClass').each((i, node)=>node.id = "sliderWeb-" + i);
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) supports a function.

```js
$('li').attr('id', function (i) { return "sliderWeb-" + i } );
// $('li').attr('id', i => 'sliderWeb-' + i );
```

```css
li::after { 
    content: attr(id);
    color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>A-</li>
  <li>B-</li>
  <li>C-</li>
  <li>D-</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: probably a better answer than mine

Answer (score 0):

Using the function [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) will help you.

```js
$.each($('li.myClass'), function(idx, obj) {
  $(obj).attr('id', 'sliderWeb-'+ idx).html('id = sliderWeb-' + idx);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class='myClass'>
</li>
<li class='myClass'>
</li>
<li class='myClass'>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be more like:

```
$('li.myClass').each(increment, element){
  $(element).attr('id', 'sliderWeb-'+increment);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

var listItems = $('li.myClass');

for(var i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++) {

```
listItems[i].setAttribute('id', 'sliderWeb-' + i);
```

}

Comment: Should use an `.each()` loop in jQuery.

Comment: Hey @PHPglue can you clarify that a bit? I mean why is it proffered to use .each instead of for loop?

Comment: It looks like you think the jQuery gives you an Array that can be effected by regular JavaScript, jQuery uses `.attr()`.